# Trying to track progress this month vs Previous

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datediff, dateadd

This sounded simple but it doesnt work like I thought. 
I am trying to track progress for Month to date 
Here is my code for MTD

`Startdate>=DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Convert(date, getdate())), 0)`

Its extremely simple.

For Last Months Start I use:
`Startdate>= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getdate()) , 0)` 
as the start date

and for the current marker I used this:
`Enddate>=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()-30), 0)+datepart (day,getdate())`

Ideally I want to know that if today is the 5th. How many sales took place in that window.
then I want to also know how we did in the same period the last month.

My problem is I find on months with 31 days that follow months with 29 days I have issues.

Is there a function that gives me the same date a month ago ?

Comment: `dateadd(month, -1, getdate())` i.e. `dateadd(month, -1, '20150330')` returns '2015-02-28'

Comment: What do you want to have happen if the same date didn't exist in the previous month?

Comment: Looks like Horaciux version works!! Thank you sir/madam!

Comment: If you have the wrong date via string manipulation it gives an error that your trying to convert something that cannot be converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dateadd(month, -1, getdate())
```

i.e. `dateadd(month, -1, '20150330')` returns '2015-02-28'

If exact day doesn't exist in previous month returns last day of month.